# Proving 9 divides a cubic by Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have just started to cover induction mathematics in my Discrete Mathematics class and I'm a little confused as to where to go with this problem.  Am I on the right track?

Prove that 9 divides (n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3) when using some integer k >= 0

Basis case: n=0, n=1

(0^3 + (0+1)^3 + (0+2)^3)/9 = (0 + 1 + 8)/9

= 9/9 = 1   TRUE

(1^3 + (1+1)^3 + (1+2)^3)/9

= (1 + 8 + 27)/9

= 36/9 = 4  TRUE

Induction hypothesis:  For fixed number k >= 0, S(k): is true where:

(k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3)/9

Prove that S(k+1) is true for all numbers k >= 0:

S(k+1):     ((k+1)^3 + ((k+1)+2)^3 + ((k+1)+3)^3)/9

((k+1)(1+2+3)^3)/9

((k+1) * 9^3)/9

Im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting, I just started an account today.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-inductive proof: $n^3+(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3=3\underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{3\text{ consecutive integers}}+\underbrace{9(n^2+2n+1)}_{\text{divisible by }9}$

Three consecutive integers must have one of them divisible by $3$.

You wrote $\frac{(k+1)^3 + ((k+1)+2)^3 + ((k+1)+3)^3}{9}=\frac{(k+1)(1+2+3)^3}{9}$, which is incorrect. Also then you wrote $1+2+3=9$.

$$\begin{align}(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3&=k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3-k^3\\&=\underbrace{k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3}_{\text{inductive hypothesis}}+\underbrace{9 (k^2+3 k+3)}_{\text{ divisible by }9}\end{align}$$

Comment: How  does the $(k+1)^3 - k^3$ come about from $(k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3$

Comment: @DavidC85 It is easy to see that $(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3=k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^2+(k+3)^3-k^3$. They are equal simply because $k^3-k^3=0$.

Comment: $k^3 - k^3 = 0$ makes sense, Im just not sure how that got us from the $(k+1)^3 + (k+2)^3 + (k+3)^3$ to the $(k^3 + (k+1)^3 + (k+2)^2 + (k+3)^3 - k^3$
How do we get another $(k+3)^3$ and the other values reduce by one and the $(k+3)^3$ turns into a $(k+2)^2$ I dont understand the power drop

Comment: @DavidC85 You want to prove that given that $k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3$ is divisible by $9$ we also have that $(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3$ is divisible by $9$. So, like Reveillark says, you want to get $(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+(k+3)^3=k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3+\text{X}$ where $X$ is anything and then prove that $X$ is divisible by $9$.

Comment: ok, so I get that adding the $k^3 - k^3$ to the end of the problem doesnt change the problem.  I still dont understand the power reduction of the third term and how the $k^3$ added, when adding $k^3 - k^3$, turns into $(k+3)^3$

Comment: @DavidC85 the power reduction was a typo and I've edited it. So you said you agree that adding $k^3-k^3$ changes nothing. So you agree with the first equality. The second equality only uses $(k+3)^3-k^3=9(k^2+3k+3)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23166/discussion-between-davidc85-and-user31415).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Recall that $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$.

Expand $(k+1)^3 + ((k+1)+1)^3 + ((k+1)+2)^3$ to get $$(k^3+(k+1)^3+(k+2)^3)+\text{something}$$

Study that something.